# Idiomatic way of handling dynamic classes in Reagent or Re-Frame application

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

In JavaScript, a common way to handle dynamic classes is to use [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) library.

I couldn't find any alternative solutions for ClojureScript, and it seems most people are fine with using inline if statements with `(str ...)` like:

```
(str "location flex-column border-box" (if is-current " current"))
```

which to me seems fragile and tedious (see spaces handling).

I'd expect this function to work like:

```
(class-names {
  :location true
  :flex-column true
  :border-box true
  :current is-current
})
; -> "location flex-column border-box"
; or "location flex-column border-box current"
```

Or like

```
(class-names "location" "flex-column" "border-box" {
  :current is-current
})
```

Of course, writing such function manually should not be hard, but I thought this should have been solved somehow already.

Comment: so far, I have this https://gist.github.com/YurySolovyov/834e9cd6258f36d6f333fd3d0806c238

Comment: and this one https://github.com/YurySolovyov/class-names-cljs

Answer (score 1):

The underlying classnames JavaScript library with all its performance optimizations is available via cljsjs: 
https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/blob/master/classnames/README.md

Comment: The problem there is that you'd have to constantly convert from CLJS maps to JS objects, so that will drop performance anyway